# BC30456: 'Checked' is not a member of 'checkbox'

Tags: vb.net

I have a gridView control with a checkBox TemplateField. I am trying to delete records from the gridvie based on the checked checkbox control but keep getting the error

> BC30456: 'Checked' is not a member of 'checkbox'.

below is my button_click subroutine which should do the delete.

```
Protected Sub DeleteSelectedProducts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteSelectedProducts.Click
    Try
        Dim atLeastOneRowDeleted As Boolean = False

        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

            Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("ProductSelector")
            If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then

                atLeastOneRowDeleted = True

                Dim productID As Integer = _
                    Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)

                DeleteResults.Text &= String.Format( _
                    "This would have deleted ProductID {0}<br />", productID)

            End If
        Next
        DeleteResults.Visible = atLeastOneRowDeleted
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: And is this Windows Forms, ASP.NET, something else?

Comment: its webForms, Asp,NET. VB

Comment: Then I suspect you've got another `CheckBox` type somewhere. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is WPF since both the [**WinForms `CheckBox`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [**ASP.NET `CheckBox`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx) have a `Checked` property.

For WPF you gotta use [**`CheckBox.IsChecked`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.IsChecked Then
```

Comment: Hi Visual Vincent; thanks for your suggestion but i am actually doing WebForms and not WinForms. using checkBox.IsChecked on WebForms will throw exceptions.

Comment: @uchenna : I suggested WPF, not WinForms (but that's not really relevant now :)). As you can see in [**the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) a WebForms check box _should_ have a `Checked` property, so it's odd that it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @uchenna : Can you place the text cursor (selection) on the `CheckBox` word in `Dim cb As CheckBox` and press F12? Doing so should open the `Object Browser` showing that type. Then post a screenshot of that so I can see the exact type and its properties.